# R weird behavior with geom_abline()

Tags: r, geom

I am using this code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = '#376795', size = 1) +  
  geom_abline(intercept = 34.232237, slope = -4.539474, linetype = 'dashed')
```

And I get this graph:

[image]

Then I comment out the middle line of code with command + shift + c

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  # geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = '#376795', size = 1) +  
  geom_abline(intercept = 34.232237, slope = -4.539474, linetype = 'dashed')
```

I get a graph without any lines. Where did the line from geom_abline() go?

[image]

I then switch the order and be careful with the + signs...

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 34.232237, slope = -4.539474, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = '#376795', size = 1)
```

[image]

Both lines are back. So the code for geom_abline() seemed fine, right?

So I then comment out the middle line:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  # geom_abline(intercept = 34.232237, slope = -4.539474, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = '#376795', size = 1)
```

[image]

The geom_smooth() is there but not the abline. I'm really confused by this behavior. I really just want the abline and not the smooth but this doesn't work:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 34.232237, slope = -4.539474, linetype = 'dashed')
```

[image]

There must be a simple reason. But also - why is the behavior inconsistent? It feels like a bug because the same code in one place seems to work and in another place doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to plot only the abline:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_blank() +   
  geom_abline(intercept = 34.232237, slope = -4.539474, linetype = 'dashed')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: ah ok I see I need geom_blank(). Why doesn't geom_abline() work without geom_blank()?